# How do I separate numbers before and after a decimal point in tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a column with Number(decimal) data type in Tableau.

How do I split it into two columns-

For example: I want to split 20.345 into 20 in one column and 345 in another column in Tableau

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to get the left side. Let's say your decimal source column is called "Value". To get the left side, you want the "Floor". Tableau doesn't have a Floor function, but you can achieve the same like this:

```
//Floor Function
IF [Value]==INT([Value]) THEN
    [Value] 
ELSEIF [Value]<0 THEN
    INT([Value]-1) 
ELSE
    INT([Value])
END
```

[Source: Tableau Community](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000CWdbC/floor-and-ceiling-functions)

Once you have the left side, the right side is simple subtraction. Just subtract the left side from the source value. This would get you a decimal still. So, if your original value was 35.123, it would get your 0.123. If all you want is 123, then you are going to need to convert it to a string and remove "0.". You cannot make it an integer, otherwise you will lose leading zeros if you original number is something like 35.0123.